# Update directX texture

Tags: directx, textures, directx-9

How can I solve following task: some app need to

1. use dozens dx9 terxtures (render them with dx3d)
   and
2. update some of them (whole or in part).

I.e. sometimes (once per frame/second/minute) i need to write bytes (`void *`) in different formats (*argb*, *bgra*, *rgb*, *888*, *565*) to some sub-rect of existing texture.
In openGL solution is very simple - `glTexImage2D`. But here unfamiliar platform features completely confused me.
Interested in solution for both dx9 and dx11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To update a texture, make sure the texture is created in D3DPOOL_MANAGED memory pool.

```
D3DXCreateTexture( device, size.x, size.y, numMipMaps,usage, textureFormat, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &texture );
```

Then call LockRect to update the data

```
RECT rect  = {x,y,z,w};  // the dimensions you want to lock
D3DLOCKED_RECT lockedRect = {0}; // "out" parameter from LockRect function below
texture->LockRect(0, &lockedRect, &rect, 0);

// copy the memory into lockedRect.pBits
// make sure you increment each row by "Pitch"

unsigned char* bits = ( unsigned char* )lockedRect.pBits; 
for( int row = 0; row < numRows; row++ )
{
    // copy one row of data into "bits", e.g. memcpy( bits, srcData, size )
    ...

    // move to the next row
    bits += lockedRect.Pitch;
}

// unlock when done
texture->UnlockRect(0);
```